# Reading chars in C

Tags: c

I wrote the following program to understand the behavior of EOF:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main ()

    char c = 0;

    printf("Enter some chars, EOF stops printing:");

    while ((c == getc(stdin)) != EOF) 
        printf("c = %c, (int) c = %d\n", c, (int) c);

    return 0;
}
```

However, if I input something such as `abcd` I get this output:

```
c = a, (int) c = 97
c = a, (int) c = 97
c = a, (int) c = 97
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got a `==` instead of a `=` so you never store whatever `getc` returns:

```
while ((c == getc(stdin)) != EOF) {
          ^^
```

And of course `c` should be `int`, not `char`.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that c should be int. This is unintuitive, so it needs pointing out.

Comment: Well, doesn't `char` already capture negative values (-128 to -1)? Using char does work when I enter EOF.

Answer (score 1):

You must read the documentation better; `getc()` returns `int`, because `EOF` doesn't fit in a `char`.

Also, you're using both `scanf()` and `getc()`, which will make things confusing due to the input stream buffering.

Try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

    int c = 0;

    printf("Enter some chars, EOF stops printing:");
    while ((c = getc(stdin)) != EOF) {
        printf("c = %c, (int) c = %d\n", c, c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I also added the missing `}` in your code, and removed the cast of `c` in the call to `printf()`, that's not needed now that `c` is `int`. This is the proper type for the `%c` formatting specifier too, by the way.

Comment: I'm aware of this, but replacing the type of `c` from `char` to `int` also does not work.